# Django: ImageField disable image deletion

Tags: python, django, django-models

Greetings
Having an ImageField object in my Foo model as such:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='foobar', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want Foo to disable to delete the uploaded photo once a Foo object is deleted and a specific . How can I do this?

Ie:

```
If self.name == "foo":
    #skip deleting the image from the harddisk.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best thing is to write a custom File Storage:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/#howto-custom-file-storage

override the delete method and set it the like described in

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class